# Netty: Can IdleStateHandler be used outside of channelPipeline?

Tags: java, sockets, server, netty

I'm able to use the IdleStateHandler for when a client is connected and detect if there is no incoming traffic. Is there any way I can use it when a client is not connected? Kind of like a heartbeat.

Comment: Can you describe a bit better your use-case ? Maybe what you really want is using EventLoop.scheduleAtFixedRate(...) ?

Comment: I'm making a server for a sensor(client), and every ten minutes the client is suppose to send a message to the server. If no message is received, then I assume the client is not working. But the client only connects to the server right before it sends a message and disconnects immediately. So IdleStateHandler is kind of useless.

Comment: @NormanMaurer I'm a little lost on how to implement the EventLoop.scheduleAtFixedRate()  method.

Comment: You would not implement it but get an EventLoop instance and call it there.

Comment: @NormanMaurer Sorry, I'm looking at the java docs but I'm not understanding the EventLoop. The only method I see is parent(). Where should I call the instance? And would the worker group be the one to call it?